# Submit form in two different ways

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with two "a" links. Both should submit form, but in two different ways.

This is html I currently have.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="doc_form" target="somwhere">
<textarea name="doc_text"><?php echo $file; ?></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
        </form>
        <a id="doc_send_email" class="btn">SEND</a>
        <a id="pritn_pdf_btn" onclick="document.getElementById('doc_form').submit();" class="btn">Print <span class="span_pdf">PDF </span></a>
```

When user clicks on `#pritn_pdf_btn`, then the form is submitted to `index.php` with `target="somwhere"`. On server side I am generating pdf with value from textarea and this PDF is opened in new tab (`target="somwhere"` is some trick that opens pdf in new tab).

However, now I also need submit form on `#doc_send_email` click. In this case I also need to generate PDF, but it should be sent to provided email and then it should show confirmation message on the same page. So:

1. In `index.php` I need somehow distinguish what caused form submission (`pritn_pdf_btn`) or (`doc_send_email`). If I would be able to set some variable on `#pritn_pdf_btn.click` and on `#doc_send_email.click` and then sent it via `POST`, it would help. But I could not find sollution.
2. I need some way to submit form with `target="somwhere"` and without `target="somwhere"`. Probably, there is someway on the `#pritn_pdf_btn.click` and on `#doc_send_email.click` to submit form with and without target?

Comment: Why not add actual submit elements? You can give each of them a different value, which you can read server side to determine the right action. Mind though, that when the user presses enter, the form may get posted without any of the submit values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to do it with multiples submit buttons like this:

```
<form method="post" id="doc_form" target="somwhere">
    <textarea name="doc_text"><?php echo $file; ?></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
    <input type="submit" name="email" value="1" id="doc_send_email" class="btn" value="SEND"/>
    <input type="submit" name="pdf" value="1" id="pritn_pdf_btn" class="btn" value="Print PDF"/>
</form>
```

Then at backend (asuming it is PHP)

```
 if($_POST['email'])
   sendEmail();
 else
   generatePDF();
```

Or by using JS:

```
<form method="post" id="doc_form" target="_self">
   <textarea name="doc_text"><?php echo $file; ?></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
   <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="generate" />
 </form>
 <a id="doc_send_email" onclick="document.getElementById('action').value='email';document.getElementById('doc_form').submit();" class="btn">SEND</a>
 <a id="pritn_pdf_btn" onclick="document.getElementById('action').value='generatePdf';document.getElementById('doc_form').target='somwhere';document.getElementById('doc_form').submit();" class="btn">Print <span class="span_pdf">PDF </span></a>
```

Then at backend (asuming it is PHP)

```
 if($_POST['action']=='email')
   sendEmail();
 else
   generatePDF();
```

Comment: And how to control form "target" part. I wish the on pritn_pdf_btnI have form with target="somwhere", but on doc_send_email click I want the form without any target? (I can change "a" to "submit" if necessary, but how to be able to control target)?

Comment: Updated my answer,look at JS solution how i change the target before submiting, but you shouldn't do it. You should make the pdf downloaded in the same tab.